# изменение textbox1.Text другой формы

Tags: c#, winforms, xml

есть в Form2 метод

```
public string TextBox
        {
            get { return textBox1.Text; }
            set { textBox1.Text = value; }
        }
```

и нужно из Form1 изменить textBox1.Text. Делаю так

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2()
{
    TextBox = homework.Attributes[0].InnerText //считывание из xml-файла
};
```

Но это не работает. Подскажите, как сделать правильно или тут всё правильно и это я где-то накосячил

Comment: Почему вы не написали ошиб\ку?

Comment: @Alex78191 ошибки никакой нет потому что. Всё компилируется. Вывожу textBox1.Text, а он пустой

Comment: как вы форму отображаете?

Comment: @Alex78191 Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog(); делал так, но после того, как вы спросили написал Form2.Instance.ShowDialog(); и всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

вместо

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(); 
f2.ShowDialog();
```

написал

```
Form2.Instance.ShowDialog();
```

Instance - это ссылка

```
public static Form2 Instance { get; set; }
        static Form2()
        {
            Instance = null;
        }
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Instance = this;
        }
```

Comment: Вы создавали и открывали новую пустую форму, вместо открытия существующей.